# Setup.py with py2app including pip packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2app

I built a keylogger in python and I used py2exe (version 0.13) to convert the python file to an exe. It worked perfectly, it included all the packages and everything. 


I want my keylogger to come to mac also, so I tried to use py2app. I followed TheBlackBerryChannels [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4ykDbciXa80). It was pretty good explaining everything but it didn't show how to install external packages that are installed from pip. Becuase I use the `from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import os
import datetime
from pathlib import Path`
 packages from pip.


In the full setup.py file this is what I have:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['KeyLoggingMac.py']
OPTIONS = {
# 'iconfile':'logoapp.icns',
 'argv_emulation': True,
 'packages': ['pynput']
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesn't include the `pynput` package, I figured that it would auto-include the `os, datetime, and pathLib` modules but why doesn't it include the `pynput`?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity sake in your main file import it like this:

```
from pynput import keyboard
```

Then in your setup file use 'includes' in OPTIONS, note that I also added the data file test.txt to write the key presses to a file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['TEST.py']
DATA_FILES = ['test.txt']
OPTIONS = {'includes': ['pynput']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Then from your venv run py2app with the terminal command:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

You can also use py2applet to generate setup.py files but I find it never works properly.

```
py2applet --make-setup FILENAME.py
```

You will also need to give the app permission to access your global keyboard events. This is done in Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy

Up to Mojave you want the Accessibility tab then add your app in there, on Catalina you want Input Monitoring.

This works for me.